# how to get a name from a line in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that accepts someone's id, and the script should print this person's name! now the problem I have is that the name is unknown!

in the directory I am in right now I have a file and in this file there are lines and each line is in the following format :

> id_number(from 6 digits)   name(can be in any length and can include number at the end)   number_of_brothers(positive number between
>   0-10)     more_random numbers(from 6 digits too but this is optional
>   which means it might not be any number in here )

the name can include a number at the end and also after the name, there must be a number that resembles the number of brothers, and after that, it is optional the line include numbers of id after the number of a brother ( whereas I said the number od is contained 6 digits)
    (also there could be spaces in the start of the line and at least one space between every two numbers or names)
    for example:

> 234218      Dan Simon 1 3   234122  234118  104134

(here the name i want to get is "Dan simon 1")

another example:

> 236501  chris brown singer 3

(the name I want to get here is "chris brown singer" )

my problem is how o get the name ! because the name could include a lot of words and also a number!

I started by getting rid of the extra spaces in the line and done grep to get the line that includes the correct id

```
#!/bin/bash

line = `grep ^$1 names_file`
correct_line=`echo $line`
```

Comment: Your first line almost certainly doesn't do what you want it to due to the spaces around the `=`. Would it be true to say that you want the 2nd, 3rd and 4th fields of the line, where each field is separated by one or more spaces?

Comment: so i should first remove the spaces and the then look for the lines that start with the given id ?

Comment: What you should do is make it clear what you are trying to do, since it's difficult to know `1` after `Dan simon` should be included, but `3` after `chris brown singer` shouldn't be.

Comment: i did explain that the name can include number at the end and also after the name there must be a number that resembles the number of brothers ,, and after that it is optional the line include numbers of id after the number of brother ( whre as i saied the number od is contains 6 digits)

Comment: Obviously, the name file is badly formatted.  A file should never have field separators inside the fields.

Comment: Can you change the file so it's easier to parse? This is a nightmare.

Comment: i tried my best to explain the file constructre !

Comment: i mean my problem is just how to get the name from the line !! because it can has more than a word and can have a number at the end

Comment: If you are in control of the file structure, don't use spaces as the field separator. Your data should look like this: `234218,Dan Simon 1,3,234122,234118,104134` -- then it would be simple to take the 2nd field.

Answer (score 1):

**Input file:**

```
cat file
234218 Dan simon 1 3 234122 234118 104134
236501 chris brown singer 3
123456 John Right 2nd 5
```

Here is pure bash regex solution:

```
re='^[0-9]{6} +([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*) +[0-9]{1,2}( +[0-9]{6,})*$'

while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done < file

Dan simon 1
chris brown singer
John Right 2nd
```

---

Using `gnu grep`:

```
grep -oP '^\d{6,}\s+\K[\w\s]+?(?=\s+\d{1,2}(?:\s+\d{6,})*$)' file    
Dan simon 1
chris brown singer
John Right 2nd
```

**Details:**

- `^\d{6,}\s+`: Match 6+ digits followed by 1+ whitespace at the start
- `\K`: Reset the match
- `[\w\s]+?`: Match 1+ word or space characters
- `(?=\s+\d{1,2}(?:\s+\d{6,})*$)`: Lookahead to ensure we have age number 1 or 2 digits ahead

Comment: i didn't fully understand this sulotion :\ isn't there is a more simple way to do it maybe usiing cut ? also the first line should print  "Dan simon 1"

Comment: Your regex needs more help at the end: `^\d{6,}\s+\K.+?(?=\s+\d{1,2}(\s+\d{6,})*$)` -- that should find the 1 or 2 digit number followed optionally by some 6+digit numbers until the end.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman I have just modified this regex as you have suggested.

Comment: @newprogrammerha You can't use `cut` because the number of fields you need is variable, and `cut` can't count from the end of the line.

Comment: yeah you are right :( i am trieng to find something else

Comment: i actually can't use what this sultion cause we didn't learn it

Comment: You cannot learn unless you try to learn. I have provided explanation of regex used for you to get started. Go through that and feel free to ask if you have any specific question or doubt.

Comment: you didn't understand me , i want to learn about it ofcourse bur since our professor didn't teach us about this method unfortnatly i can't use it ! if i know this method existed before i waoud have expalined that i can't use it

Comment: I have added a pure bash solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could parse the file with awk

```
awk '{
  # search backwards to find the first number between 0 and 10
  for (i = NF; i > 2; i--) {
    if (0 <= $i && $i <= 10) {
      brothers_col = i
      break
    }
  }
  if (i == 2) next          # did not find a name, skip this line
  name = ""
  for (i = 2; i < brothers_col; i++) {
    name = name $i OFS
  }
  print name
' file
```